# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ModalController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I used to have all my code in one big js file, but i separated everything -- including controllers to make it modular as my little app grows (and for learning porpoises). So my ui-bootstrap modal code is in this controller and is called and worked fine.  When i split the controllers into separate files i get the error below.  How do i fix?

**app.js**

```
var personApp = angular.module('PersonApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

**personController.js**

```
personApp.controller('PersonController', function ($scope, $uibModal, PersonService) {
    $scope.addPerson = function () {
        $scope.modalModel = {
            Id: 0,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            birthDate: ''
        };
        $scope.$uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Modal/AddEditPersonModal',
            controller: 'ModalController',
            scope: $scope
        })
    }
```

**personModalController.js**

```
personApp.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.$uibModalInstance.close();
        var modalId = $scope.modalModel.Id;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            var person = $scope.persons[i];
            if (person.Id === $scope.oldValues.Id) {
                $scope.persons[i].firstName = $scope.oldValues.firstName;
                $scope.persons[i].lastName = $scope.oldValues.lastName;
                $scope.persons[i].birthDate = $scope.oldValues.birthDate;
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<link href="~/Content/PageSpecific/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/filters/personFilter.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/services/personService.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/controllers/personController.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/controllers/personModalController.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PageSpecific/Index.js"></script>


<div ng-app="PersonApp" class="container">
    <div ng-controller="PersonController">
        <div class="mb20 mt15">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Person" ng-model="searchPerson" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right mb15 mr20" data-toggle="modal" ng-model="addPersonModel" ng-click="addPerson()">Add New</button>
        </div>

        <table class="table header-fixed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-click="sortData('Id')">
                        ID <div ng-class="getSortClass('Id')"></div>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sortData('firstName')">
                        First Name <div ng-class="getSortClass('firstName')"></div>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sortData('lastName')">
                        Last Name <div ng-class="getSortClass('lastName')"></div>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sortData('birthDate')">
                        BirthDate <div ng-class="getSortClass('birthDate')"></div>
                    </th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in filteredPersons | orderBy: sortColumn:reverseSort | filter : searchPerson">
                    <td>{{person.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.birthDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" data-toggle="icon-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Record" ng-model="editPersonModel" ng-click="editPerson(person)"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
                        <a href="" data-toggle="icon-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Remove Record" ng-model="removePersonModel" ng-click="removePersonDialog(person)"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul uib-pagination total-items="persons.length" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" items-per-page="numPerPage" num-pages="numPages"></ul>
        <pre>Page: {{currentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: you have added `personModalController.js` in script but your file name is `modalController.js`

Comment: my index.cshtml main controller is personController.js.  From inside there (via my code in OP) i call the personModalControllers.js...

Comment: tip : you must use `controllerAs` syntax  and you can send data to modal controller via `resolve` property  of  `$uibModal.open` method.

Comment: @Ved that returns new error in browser dev tools: angular.js:13920 ReferenceError: ModalController is not defined

Comment: @pro.mean not sure how that works, i'm 5 days into angular

Comment: @tshoemake. You are correct. My mistake.

Comment: @Ved I wish i wasn't :]

Comment: Can you create fiddle or plunkr with your HTML and both js code.

Comment: @Ved I haven't used plunker before but i feel like it'd take me more time to make that than actually solve the problem.  Is there another way

Comment: Accoring to me, issue is Either here  : controller: 'ModalController', or with ModalController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was a simple mistake on my part. Changed the order of referenced files in the index.cshtml.  personController had function trying to call modalcontroller (in personmodalcontroller)

This:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/controllers/personController.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/controllers/personModalController.js"></script>
```

Became this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/controllers/personModalController.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PersonApp/controllers/personController.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to include,`$uibModalInstance`

```
personApp.controller('ModalController', ['$scope' function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.$uibModalInstance.close();
        var modalId = $scope.modalModel.Id;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            var person = $scope.persons[i];
            if (person.Id === $scope.oldValues.Id) {
                $scope.persons[i].firstName = $scope.oldValues.firstName;
                $scope.persons[i].lastName = $scope.oldValues.lastName;
                $scope.persons[i].birthDate = $scope.oldValues.birthDate;
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, don't in include that in $scope when i pass it in? $scope.$uibModalInstance =$uibModal.open({})...

Comment: in personController.js you are using .$uibModalInstance but you have not included that.

Comment: I included in the modalcontroller like you said and same error

Comment: It seems issue is not with dependency. Have you included modalController.js path inside your HTML and check the code inside modalController.js. Some error may be there.

Comment: the code worked before and is identical.. i was actually WAS missing the path in my view (this is an mvc project). I added it to the cshtml and it still doesn't work.  I'm running out of ideas.... i thought for sure you nailed it with reference

Comment: Have you provided the module name in HTML; <html ng-app="personApp">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129203/discussion-between-ved-and-tshoemake).

Answer (score 0):

Re define the ModalController like this. You have not injected the `$uibModalInstance` dependency in your controller. the `$uibModalInstance` inside the function parameters are only the alias reference to your dependency. You have to inject the dependency first before aliasing the dependency.

```
personApp.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.$uibModalInstance.close();
        var modalId = $scope.modalModel.Id;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            var person = $scope.persons[i];
            if (person.Id === $scope.oldValues.Id) {
                $scope.persons[i].firstName = $scope.oldValues.firstName;
                $scope.persons[i].lastName = $scope.oldValues.lastName;
                $scope.persons[i].birthDate = $scope.oldValues.birthDate;
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This doesnt work.  With $uibModalInstance it is used internally in the function